# xamarin binding class property

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding, derived-class

I'm am trying to make a small app for android through xamarin. I'm also trying to include some MVVM.
I have a model class UserInfoM (with a name, password, ...). I have a viewmodel "mainpageVM" in which I want to use that class UserInfoM . This works until a certain pount. When i type something in the app, the getter and setter from the UserInfoM(odel) are triggered. But i can't seem to get the data in the VM. This is probably going to be some obvious mistake, but after searching a few days, i can't seem to find the answer.

In my view (xaml) I have bindings to the Viewmodel and the

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainPageVM/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

...

```
    <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Enter Username"
           Text="{Binding UserInfo.User, Mode=TwoWay}"                
        >
        <Entry.BindingContext>
            <local:MainPageVM/>
        </Entry.BindingContext>
```

In my MainPageVM use the UserInfoM(odel) as a property:

```
    public UserInfoM UserInfo
    {
        get { return _userInfo ?? (_userInfo = new UserInfoM()); }
        set
        {
            _userInfo = value;
        }
    }
```

And in my UserInfoM(odel) I have the following property (amongst others):

```
    private string user;
    public string User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set
        {
            if (user != value)
            {
                user = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(User));
            }
        }
    }
```

So the xaml binding seems to work since the User-property getter and setter are triggerd. But only in the model, although in the view the binding is set to the MainPageVM. In the MainPageVM all the model-properties stay empty. It has to be some kind of logical error, i don't get errors, the entry is filled in nicely, the user-property in the UserInfoM(odel) is filled in (set) by the Entry-field but I can't access/use the UserInfo.User (or other) property from the model.

In short, i can bind a single property, but not one in from another class with properties. I watch a bunch of tutorials and searched a lot but can't find this.
I hope the explanation is clear enough... Any help would be much appreciated.
The raiseproperty-method implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and work perfect for a single property. The user-property in de UserInfoM(odel) is updated but not the one in the Viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly set the BindingContext to your Entry. When you have set the binding context to your page, it applies to all elements inside it. Your binding of the Entry is correct, so it should become like this:

```xml
<Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Enter Username" 
    Text="{Binding UserInfo.User, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

If you replace your code like this, the Entry will successfully find its BindingContext (from the page's one), it will look inside it in order to find UserInfo class and it will bind the UserInfo's User property to the Entry's Text property.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was a simple as that., now it seems to work as exptected.

Comment: Glad that it worked! Since you are new to the community, when an answer is the correct one, please mark is with a green checkmark, so that it can help others (they will see that this answer did indeed solved your issue). :)

Comment: Ok, done. Didn't know the green check-mark. Thanks for the tip, I'll keep it mind for the future.